# Duvida TD Jquery

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de recuperar o nome de uma classe de um `TD`, segue meu código.

```
var dateSelectClick = $(target.element.text);
console.log(dateSelectClick);
```

retorno disso é `n.fn.init {}`

pois eu gostaria que retornasse uma string com o nome da classe por exemplo

> day calendar-day-2016-03-27 calendar-dow-0

---

Vou explicar melhor,

Eu tenho um valor em um TD e preciso recuperar ele, é um calendario e cada data que eu clico do calentario existe uma classe diferente em cada data, preciso que, quando eu clique nessa data eu consiga recuperar o dia mes e ano do dia que eu cliquei, eu tenho o seguinte retorno executando esse código.

resumindo preciso recuperar essa data que esta aparecendo no console, mas nao consigo isso que preciso saber como fazer =)

var dateSelectClick = $(target);
          console.log(dateSelectClick);

segue uma print com o retorno do console.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Podes completar/[edit] a pergunta? dá ideia que ficaste a meio. Podes explicar melhor o que queres dizer com "classe"?

Comment: Você deseja recuperar o nome da classe da TD em que tipo de evento? Clicando nessa TD?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é o que você procura, mas tente adaptar seu codigo a isso com jQuery:

```
$("seu_elemento").attr("class");
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente percorrer o objeto

```
var objData = $(target);
var dateSelect = "";

$('elemento').click(function(){

 $.each(objData,function(i,e){
    dateSelect = e.data._i; //copia o valor da data para variavel dateSelect
  });

});
```